How to use MediaElement of UWP to show picture?
In the UWP application, a MediaElement is used to play video, audio and picture.
For video and audio play, it works well. But for picture, something is wrong with it.
The code is below. When I select a picture, e.g. a png file, then you can see the error info shown on MediaElement video.

Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path

 private async void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       //Create a new picker
       FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();

       //Add filetype filters.  In this case wmv and mp4.
       filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
       filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
       filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
       filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

       //Set picker start location to the video library
       filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

       //Retrieve file from picker
       StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

       //If we got a file, load it into the media element
       if (file != null)
       {
           IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
           video.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
       }
   }

The error info: 
The source code comes from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/basicmediacasting/
My final target is to cast video, audio and picture to remote smart TV via DLNA, but blocked here.

MediaElement only support formats that can be streamed, thus video and audio formats works, but images are not.
To make it work you have to convert image to a video.
private async void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Create a new picker
    FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    
    //Add filetype filters.  In this case wmv and mp4.
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    
    //Set picker start location to the video library
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
    
    //Retrieve file from picker
    StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    
    if (file == null)
    {
        //Show error message
        return;
    }

    //If we got an image, convert it to video
    if (file.ContentType.StartsWith("image/"))
    {
        //TODO: Create video from the image and save it to temp location
        //TODO: Replace current file variable with newly created video file

        if(file == null)
        {
            //Show error message
            return;
        }
    }


    IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    video.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
}

